# Data ingestion in elasticsearch with database having large number of tables

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"
    jdbc_user => "mysql"
    parameters => { "favorite_artist" => "Beethoven" }
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * from songs where artist = :favorite_artist"
  }
}
```

In the above logstash configuration file how to ingest data?
What to do when I have to select multiple tables?

Comment: hi u can join or union/ union all  to get data from mysql   to ingest  data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data would be getting ingested based on the "Select statement query". if you want to 
    have the data from multiple tables, then you can have join queries combining all the 
    tables and the relevant output from the query would be ingested to ES.It all depends 
    on your specific use case.  Here is some sample pasted down for your reference.

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"
jdbc_user => "mysql"
parameters => { "favorite_artist" => "Beethoven" }
schedule => "* * * * *"
statement => "SELECT * FROM songs INNER JOIN song_folder using song_number ORDER BY 
song_title;"
}
}

output{
elasticsearch{
hosts=>"http://xx:XX:XX:XX:9200"
index=>"song"
document_type=>"songname"
document_id=>"song_title"
}
stdout{codec=>rubydebug}
}


Please let me know , if you have any further queries.
```